# Do these two postgres expressions give same results?

Tags: postgresql

I have two fields with range type.

Are these two `where` expressions will give same results?

```
where range1 && range2

where not isempty( range1 * range2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

They will, indeed.
Both overlap operator (`&&`) and intersection (`*`) are evaluated correctly, including cases where the 2 ranges have a common bound and their intersection:

- only contains 1 element (= the bound is included in both)
- contains no elements (= the bound is not included in at least 1 of the 2 ranges)

The following query tests pretty much all the cases (= intersections with more than 1 point, exactly 1 point, 0 points but "close", "truly" 0 points, and all the combinations of lower/upper bounds inclusions):

```
WITH r(range) AS (
    VALUES (numrange(0,1,'[]')), (numrange(1,2,'[]')), (numrange(0,2,'[]')), (numrange(5,6, '[]')),
           (numrange(0,1,'[)')), (numrange(1,2,'[)')), (numrange(0,2,'[)')), (numrange(5,6, '[)')),
           (numrange(0,1,'(]')), (numrange(1,2,'(]')), (numrange(0,2,'(]')), (numrange(5,6, '(]')),
           (numrange(0,1,'()')), (numrange(1,2,'()')), (numrange(0,2,'()')), (numrange(5,6, '()'))
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT r1.range, r2.range, r1.range && r2.range AS UsingOverlap, NOT isempty(r1.range * r2.range) AS UsingIntersect
FROM r r1, r r2
) T
```

Feel free to add `WHERE UsingOverlap <> UsingIntersect`.